# Uninitialized pointer causes core dump

Tags: c, cygwin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int x[3] = {42, 44, 48};
  int *y;
  int *z;
  z=y;
  y=x;

  printf("%d, %d, %d\n", x[0], x[1], x[2]);
  printf("%d, %d, %d\n", y[0], y[1], y[2]);
  printf("%d, %d, %d\n", z[0], z[1], z[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile the code above I'm given the error message

```
tester.c: In function ‘main’:
tester.c:15:2: warning: ‘y’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
z=y;
 ^
```

and the printf result after compiling results in the Z line displaying a core dump. I'm unsure as to what I did wrong, as I've done pointers to arrays before and it hasn't resulted in a core dump.

edit: Question has been answered. Reverse order of z=y and y=x.

Comment: And where do you expect `z` to point to?

Comment: You have the sequence of assignments to `z` and `y` in the wrong order.  You assign an uninitialized value to `z`, then set `y`.  You would avoid problems if you first set `y` and then copy the result to `z`.  And it is good to pay attention to the warnings from the compiler.  Remember, especially when you're learning, it knows a lot more about C than you do.

Comment: Thanks you BLUE and Jonathan.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That should have been an answer.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>As suggested (though BLUEPIXY also gave the same core information, hence a CW answer).</sup>

You have the sequence of assignments to `z` and `y` in the wrong order. You assign an uninitialized value to `z`, then set `y`. You would avoid problems if you first set `y` and then copy the result to `z`.

And it is good to pay attention to the warnings from the compiler. Remember, especially when you're learning, it knows a lot more about C than you do.

Answer (score 1):

Initially both y and z are uninitialized. That is why 
you get warning when you set z=y(y is uninitialized here).
Now setting y=x doesn't change the value of z(still uninitialized).
So eventually you are trying to access an uninitialized pointer(z)
that is why getting error.

Answer (score 0):

include the following header file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Allocate memory to y

```
int x[3] = {42, 44, 48};
int *y;
int *z;
y=(int *) malloc (3 * sizeof (int));
z=y;
y=x;
```

before returning from the main remember to free the memory

```
free (y);
```

This should work fine.

Comment: While using `malloc()` is a valid alternative, the printing code in the question references `y[2]`, which means you need to allocate space for at least three `int` values (not just one as the code <s>currently does</s> initially did). Also, the values that `z` ends up pointing at are still uninitialized; the space allocated by `malloc()` is not initialized.